# How can I get the same int number after breaking it into its digits

Tags: c++, math

Let’s say I have 128 and I broke it up into 1, 2 and 8.
Can anyone give me a logic to build the number again from its broken digits.

Comment: 1 * 100 + 2 * 10 + 8. Or, recursively, at each step (left-to-right) multiply by ten and add the digit.

Comment: Multiply by 100, 10, 1 and add the results??

Comment: How did you break it up in the first place?  putting it back together should just be the reverse operation

Comment: @rish_7ramn Just combine them together.:)

Comment: _@rish_7ramn_ note that `'1'` isn't the same as `1`!

Comment: @lorro -- or, **iteratively**, at each step (left-to-right) multiply by ten and add the digit. There's no need for recursion here.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a vector of ints, you can do:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int to_integer( const std::vector<int>& v ) {
   int number = 0;
   for ( int value : v ) {
      number = 10*number + value;
   }   
   return number;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec {1,2,8};
    int number = to_integer( vec );
    printf( "Number:%d\n", number );
    return 0;
}
```

If it was a string, you could simply use the C library

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
...
const char* str = "128";
int number = ::atoi( str );
```

But that's likely not what you are asking.
You can do the hands-on approach

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
int to_integer( const char* str ) {
   int number = 0;
   for ( ; *str != '\0'; str++ ) {
      char ch = *str;
      number = 10*number + (ch-'0');
   }   
   return number;
}
int main() {
    const char* str = "128";
    int number = to_integer( str );
    printf( "Number:%d\n", number );
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that this routine above is just a minimal, simplistic and it does not check for cases that the C library does as eg: non-numeric charaters, white spaces, null pointer.

However many times we can guarantee all above as a precondition so the above becomes valid production code. I actually use something like that for high speed trading.

Comment: The question is not about how to convert a string to an integer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  Yep I added another implementation just in case. Thank you!